# does a failover site-to-site VPN require two firewalls at the remote site

Tags: high-availability, site-to-site-vpn

We have two ISPs, each of which has assigned us a bank of public IP addresses.
Let's call the first ISP "VZON" and the second ISP "CCAST".

Telephony (VoIP) traffic goes out the VZON gateway; all other data traffic goes out the CCAST gateway.

There is a site-to-site VPN connecting a remote site via the CCAST gateway.  We would like that VPN to be "more or less highly available".

Since that's a fuzzy term, I will define what we mean by it.  If the CCAST gateway connectivity fails (perhaps CCASTS's router fails, or someone accidentally pulls the electric plug) we would like a "standby" VPN to come online automatically using the VZON gateway; and once the failure on the CCAST gateway has been fixed, we would like the VPN to revert automatically to use CCAST gateway.

**Does this scenario require two hardware firewalls at the remote site?**  Or can a single firewall (let's say some CISCO SRX model) configure two VPNs, using different gateways on the other end, and treat one of them as a "standby", bringing it online only when it detects that the remote peer is "dead" (by using Dead Peer Detection or some other method).

P.S. If a single firewall with a primary and a "standby" VPN is not possible, is it possible to have two concurrent VPNs, but have one of them get 90% of the traffic and the other 10%, again using only a single firewall at the remote site, and no additional devices, but when the connectivity on the "main" VPN fails, the load shifts automatically to 100% for the "ancillary" VPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: no, you don't need two firewalls on the remote site, rather a single firewall capable of dual WAN management, and with dual VPN peer capability. Basically any modern firewall supports these features.

Obviously, this means that a firewall failure will bring down the VPN tunnel, regardless of how many internet connections do you have. To guarantee against such possibility you had to use two firewalls to create a single high-availability cluster, a feature which is generally available on businness-oriented appliances.

Comment: Understood about firewall failure.  Does "dual VPN peer capability" allow for a primary VPN with the secondary in (automatic) standby mode?

Comment: Yes, it means you can define a VPN with two different peer IP addresses (a primary or preferred one and a secondary or backup one)